# Using the Counter function on a list in python

Tags: python, counter

We have to return the frequency of the length of words in a .txt file. 
E.g `"My name is Emily"` will be converted to a list: `["My", "name", "is", "Emily"]`, which I converted to a list of the lengths of each word: `[2, 4, 2, 5]` and then I use the function Counter which outputs a dictionary that looks like:

```
Counter({2: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

But I need it to include count of zero:

```
Counter({1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

Any ideas? 
Should I get rid of the Counter function all together?

Comment: What should be the maximum value till which you need the zeros?

Comment: For missing keys Counter already returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

`Counter` only counts the frequency of items, which means that it keeps the count of items which are present.

But, if the item you looking for is not there in the `Counter` object, it will return `0` by default.

For example,

```
print Counter()[1]
# 0
```

If you really need the items with zero count in it, then you can create a normal dictionary out of a Counter, like this

```
c = Counter({2: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1})
print {num:c[num] for num in xrange(1, max(c) + 1)}
# {1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Counter class from the collections module it is indeed implicit:

```
txt = "My name is Emily"
d = collections.Counter([len(x) for x in txt.split()])
```

d variable contains the information you mentioned without the number 1:

```
Counter({2: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

d[1] returns 0